# Struct included in two header files, neither of which I own

Tags: c++, include

I am trying to play with SCHED_DEADLINE in c++, I needed to send `struct sched_attr` to and `ioctl` so I included [`<linux/sched/types.h>`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/sched/types.h), that header also happens to include `strut sched_param`. I also included `<string>` which includes the standard headers for c++ which eventually includes [`include\bits\sched.h`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/bits/types/struct_sched_param.h.html) which also defines `struct sched_param`. The compiler (obviously) doesn't particularly like this. I used the header guard (`_BITS_TYPES_STRUCT_SCHED_PARAM`) in my code to get the compiler to not include `include\bits\sched.h`, but it feels like there should be a "better" way.

```
> Executing task in folder sched_deadline_testing: arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -o LSM9DS0 src/LSM9DS0.cpp -Wall --pedantic <

In file included from src/LSM9DS0.cpp:36:
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/linux/sched/types.h:7:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct sched_param’
 struct sched_param {
        ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/bits/sched.h:74,
                 from /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/sched.h:43,
                 from /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/pthread.h:23,
                 from /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/8/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/gthr-default.h:35,
                 from /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/8/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/gthr.h:148,
                 from /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/8/ext/atomicity.h:35,
                 from /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.h:39,
                 from /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/8/string:52,
                 from src/LSM9DS0.cpp:20:
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/bits/types/struct_sched_param.h:23:8: note: previous definition of ‘struct sched_param’
 struct sched_param
```

The code is [here](https://bitbucket.org/CombatWombat42/sched_deadline_testing/src/b35036cf38f0a9aa9084519e2fbe59edd0ffbfb9/src/LSM9DS0.cpp?at=cpp_conversion) if that's important. I have also tried this cross compiling, and compiling locally, both cause the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're out of luck. The two headers are incompatible. You simply must avoid including both `<linux/sched/types.h>` and `<string>` into the same translation unit. It's probably worth noting that being a Linux kernel header, the former is probably not intended to be used in C++, nor has there been an attempt to make it compatible.

Comment: Actually making Linux headers C++ compatible has been *actively* opposed in the past by the ones in power. [LKML FAQ 15.3](http://vger.kernel.org/lkml/). The argument being made is quite broken, but good luck changing their minds about it...